# Is using DAO in domain objects correct?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I found the following in an [article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-in-practice): "DAO classes should never be called directly from the client (Services and other consumer classes). The clients should always call the domain objects which in turn should call the DAO's for persisting the data to the data store. ".

This is not how I have seen things done before when doing DDD. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last sentence you quoted from the article could have been written more clearly.  I suspect the author meant (emphasis is my added text):

> The clients should always call the domain objects **which should call the Repository** which in turn should call the DAO's for persisting the data to the data store.

Comment: Still, I have always thought that POJOs should not have any references to the repositories?

Comment: That's the intent of the Repository pattern.  When a domain object wants to collaborate with another domain object, it asks a Repository for that object.

Comment: So I should put search and report methods (like getChildrenByABC(A a, B b, C c) in the domain objects? What about pagination (getChildren(int offset, int count) - would you put all in the domain object?

Comment: @Piotr: I don't think using repository.getChildren is really the best way.  If they are children of a parent domain entity, and you need reference to them, then they should already be loaded into the parent entity when it is retrieved from the parent's repository.  You should probably be using parentObj.Children and not repository.getChildren(parentObj).

Comment: @qstarin ok, but I was thinking of using this for searching and paging for very large collections, or do you have any better suggestion of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

> "DAO classes should never be called
>   directly from the client (Services and
>   other consumer classes). The clients
>   should always call the domain objects
>   which in turn should call the DAO's
>   for persisting the data to the data
>   store. "

No, I think that is quite wrong.

Domain objects probably shouldn't reference Repositories, either.

If a domain object needs to collaborate with other domain objects, it can raise domain events or take other domain objects as parameters to methods (in which case, the client/caller retrieves all necessary domain objects through repositories).